# Unity C# Friction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an endless runner game similar to subway surfers but I'm having trouble generating the floor for which the player runs on. For every instantiation of the floor object, I want to set the floor static and dynamic friction to zero. However when I set the dynamic friction to zero, the character runs for a short time and then stops and slowly sinks through the object.

Here's the function with the problem:

```
private void SpawnTile(int prefabIndex = -1)
{
    GameObject go;

    go = Instantiate(tilePrefabs[0]) as GameObject;

  go.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
  go.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().material.staticFriction = 0;
    go.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().material.dynamicFriction = 0;
    go.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().material.bounciness = 0;
    go.transform.SetParent(transform);
    go.transform.position = Vector3.forward * spawnZ;
    spawnZ += tileLength;
}
```

Comment: no error shows up in the editor? also just a guess, did you create the physics material beforehand?

Comment: Instead of `go.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();` try adding the collider using the editor and apply it to the prefab. Perhaps the shape of the collider is the villain here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping! I just spend a while troubleshooting and realized that the GameObject  had two sub-objects, the ground and the floor. So I realized that I wasn't adding the boxcollider to the right part of the instantiated object. So now the questions is, how would you go about adding a component to a sub object? For Ex. Floor consists of Ground and Wall, right now I am adding the box collider to Floor even though it doesn't physically exist, instead it just groups the Ground and the Wall  together. Sorry if I'm using the right terms, I'm new to Unity!